# Laravel 2 functions querybuilder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I would like to query multiple tables from multiple databases.

My first query should return an array of sites_id.

The second request should return manufacturers_id based on the sites_id returned in the first request.

How do I set this up?

My repository:

```
    public function getSitesImminence()
{
    $arraySites = PublicationSite::
    select('sites_id')
    ->where('publi_code', '=', 'imminence_intercab')
    ->where('publi_status', '>', '0')
    ->get();
    return $arraySites;
}

public function getManufacturersMls($arraySites){
    $arrayManufacturers = Site::
    select('manufacturers_list')
    ->where('sites_id', '=', $arraySites)
    ->get();
    return $arrayManufacturers;
    }
```

My controller:

```
        $toto = $siteRepository->getSitesImminence()->getManufacturersMls($arraySites);
```

My error:

```
Method getManufacturersMls does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested but your code should look more like this:

```
$arraySites = $siteRepository->getSitesImminence();
$toto = $siteRepository->getManufacturersMls($arraySites);
```

and your function should be a little different, using whereIn:

```
public function getManufacturersMls($arraySites){
    $arrayManufacturers = Site::
    select('manufacturers_list')
        ->whereIn('sites_id', $arraySites)
        ->get();
    return $arrayManufacturers;
 }
```